# Construct based on templated class

Tags: c++

I have two templated classes. Now I want to construct a new variable that has the same type as an existing variable, and with template arguments that are based on that variable.

To be more specific, I have:

```cpp
template <typename T, size_t N, size_t M>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() = default;
};

template <typename T, size_t N>
class Bar
{
public:
    Bar() = default;
};
```

This allows me to construct e.g.:

```cpp
int main()
{
    Foo<int, 2, 2> foo;
    Bar<double, 3> bar;
    return 0;
}
```

Now I want to allocate a new variable that is either `Foo` or `Bar` depending on an existing variable, and that has the same `T`, a different `N`, and the (optional) rest of the template arguments the same as the existing variable.
For the example, I would like a helper-function that can construct

```cpp
Foo<int, 2 + 2, 2>
Foo<double, 3 + 2>
```

I thought of having a helper function:

```cpp
template <template <typename, size_t, class...> class X, typename T, size_t N, class... Args>
auto construct(X<T, N, Args...>&)
{
     return X<T, N + 2, Args...>();
}
```

to do e.g.

```cpp
auto a = construct(foo);
```

But this makes my compiler unhappy:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'construct'
    auto a = construct(foo);
             ^~~~~~~~~
note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'type-parameter-0-3' against 2
auto construct(X<T, N, Args...>&)
     ^
1 error generated.
```

[Compile and try here](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:32,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:32,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:32,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:32),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctemplate+%3Ctypename,+size_t,+class...%3E+class+X,+typename+T,+size_t+N,+class...+Args%3E%0Aauto+construct(X%3CT,+N,+Args...%3E%26)%0A%7B%0A+++++return+X%3CT,+N+%2B+2,+Args...%3E()%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T,+size_t+N,+size_t+M%3E%0Aclass+Foo%0A%7B%0Apublic:%0A++++Foo()+%3D+default%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T,+size_t+N%3E%0Aclass+Bar%0A%7B%0Apublic:%0A++++Bar()+%3D+default%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++Foo%3Cint,+2,+2%3E+foo%3B%0A++++Bar%3Cdouble,+3%3E+bar%3B%0A%0A++++auto+a+%3D+construct(foo)%3B%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g111,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27%27,selection:(endColumn:5,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:5,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:5,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:5,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+11.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Comment: In `constrcut`, shouldn't `<typename, size_t, class...>` be `<typename, size_t, size_t...>` since the templates have a variable number of `size_t` parameters at the end?

Comment: @NathanOliver Here yes, in my real-life case I would like to not care about the types of the other template. Maybe I can edit to be more clear

Comment: wasnt that `Bar<double, 3 + 2>` before? `Foo<double, 3 + 2>` doesnt work, because there is no default for `M`

Comment: Unfortunately that is a hole in the language right now.  You can either have a `some_type...` to take non-type template parameters or `class...` to take type parameters.  There is no generic `...` that will take both types and non-types.

Comment: btw gccs error message looks a bit confused as well, but imho its a little more helpful

Comment: @NathanOliver Disappointing but clear... What if all the 'trailing' templates have defaults? Does that change anything? (I don't think so because I seem to need to still specify them in my helper)

Comment: No, it doesn't help.  I'm not sure if there is anything in the works to help this either.

Answer (score 1):

Type and non-type template arguments don't mix that easily. Your `construct` expects a `template <typename, size_t, class...> class X`, ie template with 1 type, 1 `size_t` and aribitrary more type arguments. `Foo` is not that. If you fix those to `size_t` your code compiles:

```
template <template <typename, size_t, size_t...> class X, 
          typename T, 
          size_t N, 
          size_t... Args>   // <--- Args are size_t not types
auto construct(X<T, N, Args...>&)
{
     return X<T, N + 2, Args...>();
}

// ....

int main() {
   Foo<int, 2, 2> foo;
   Bar<double, 3> bar;

   Foo<int,2+2,2> a = construct(foo);

   return 0;
}
```

[Complete example](https://godbolt.org/z/rjMTGMaY3)

Comment: Thanks a lot! So I would have to be specific about all the trailing arguments? What happens for a class templated `template <typename T, size_t N, size_t M, typename S>`?

Comment: @TomdeGeus you cannot mix type and non-type parameters that easily. You'd need a specialization like the one in your code. Its a rather drastic restriction, though depending on use-case there are workarounds. You could for example consider to use `std::integral_constant` instead of the `size_t`s, then its all types.